# Record the running time of a kernel function

Tags: kernel

I want to record the time spent in a function in the kernel, and then use `printk` to print it out. Is there any way I can do this? Just like:

```
time_satrt();
function();
time_end();
printk();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jiffies to measure time in kernel.Something like this

```
#include <linux/jiffies.h>
#include <linux/timer.h>

unsigned long start_time , end_time, total_time;
start_time = jiffies;
//your function code>
end_time = jiffies;
total_time = end_time - start_time;
```

There are also api's to convert jiffies to milliseconds / seconds if you are interested in printing time in milliseconds / seconds / whatever.